# How do I publish a formula?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I've been manipulating certain chemical properties and I've come up with a new formula that doesn't seem to already have been discovered. How would I go about publishing my findings?

Comment: Put it in a journal?

Comment: Look here, maybe it could help you https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_publish_a_scientific_paper